# Is there a way to prevent memory leaks from WebView (implemented on XAML) on Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I've created an app by using Windows App Studio in order to generate a content-based app from YouTube playlists and videos. The generated package was fine, but when I've started to deploy the app (using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015) in order to find memory leaks, I've discovered the leaks come from the page "YouTubeViewer.xaml" and it is related to webview grid that enables the app to display videos through YouTube APIs v.3.0. Analysing data from Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools, I've realized when I navigate through the pages of the app such as the "YouTube Videos details" page and the "Main Page", the Garbage Collector does not collect the "cache" generated from "WebViewer" in the XAML file. Consequently, the app has crashed because the application has exceeded memory limits (in my case, the app was being tested on a low memory device, a 512 RAM Windows Phone 8.1)

My doubt is: Is there a way to edit the code through "YouTubeViewer.xaml.cs" and programmatically clear the cache generated by the WebViewer in "YouTubeViewer.xaml" file?  I mean, is there any way of disposing the cache or make the app use the Garbage Collector for a WebView cache? Below there is my "YouTubeViewer.xaml.cs" code from my solution.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AppStudio.Common.Services;
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

namespace CanaltechCorporate.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class YouTubeViewer : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TitleText", typeof(string), typeof(YouTubeViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SummaryTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SummaryText", typeof(string), typeof(YouTubeViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EmbedUrlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EmbedUrl", typeof(string), typeof(YouTubeViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PageTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PageTitle", typeof(string), typeof(YouTubeViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NeedsFullScreenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NeedsFullScreen", typeof(bool), typeof(YouTubeViewer), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public YouTubeViewer()
        {
            this.Unloaded += ((sender, args) => this.EmbedUrl = null);
            this.InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().OrientationChanged += this.OnOrientationChanged;
            this.TransitionStoryboardState();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

        public string TitleText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public string SummaryText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SummaryTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SummaryTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public string PageTitle
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PageTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PageTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        public string EmbedUrl
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EmbedUrlProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EmbedUrlProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("EmbedUrl");
            }
        }

        public bool NetworkAvailable
        {
            get { return InternetConnection.IsInternetAvailable(); }
        }

        public bool NeedsFullScreen
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(NeedsFullScreenProperty); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(NeedsFullScreenProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("NeedsFullScreen");
            }
        }

        private void OnOrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
        {
            this.TransitionStoryboardState();
        }

        private async void TransitionStoryboardState()
        {
            string displayOrientation;
            StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();            

            switch (DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().CurrentOrientation)
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    await statusBar.HideAsync();
                    NeedsFullScreen = true;
                    displayOrientation = "Landscape";
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                default:
                    await statusBar.ShowAsync();
                    NeedsFullScreen = false;
                    displayOrientation = "Portrait";
                    break;
            }

            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, displayOrientation, false);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }


        }

    }

}
```